# z-index and position doesn't work

Tags: css

I have this page:
http://bable.co.il/static/index1.php?page=safety&id=7

when you hover over articles, you will get a sliding menu.
this menu comes under the the article it self. 
I tried to fix the z-index and the position of the menu with no success.

**this is for explorer 8**

I posted the link because I thought you could check the css by your self and figure what is going on.
anyway, here is the css of the ul that shows up:

```
.topnav{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and here is the css of the element that comes on top of the menu:

```
.ac_subitem{
width:90%;
right:6%;
position: relative;
margin-top:1px; /* animate to -200px */
/*background: transparent url(../images/tpl/bg_menu.png) repeat top left;*/
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,     endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

}

can anyone help please?!!

Comment: I seem to remember some older versions of IE not respecting z-index styles at all. Please add more information if you want an answer - what version of IE? show us the CSS that doesn't work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're totally missing the DOCTYPE in your page which in turn is rendering it in Quirks Mode. Add a proper DOCTYPE and it should work ok.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: this would help me but it will destroy the whole site!! isn't there another answer that works without changing this?

Comment: @ahmed you have to have a doctype defined in your document, otherwise your page will look inconsistent across browsers, that is Web design 101. I suggest you add a doctype and try to fix any issues that arise from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

To use z-index your div has to be positioned absolute in your css. Did you do that?